# Golang аргументы функции по имени

Tags: python, golang

На python можно было сделать операцию вида

```
def bar(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

args={'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}
bar(**args)
```

Как сделать что-то похожее на Go?

```
func bar( a, b, c int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %d", a, b, c)
}

func main(){
    args:=make(map[string]int)
    args["a"] = 3
    args["b"] = 2
    args["c"] = 1
    // Дальше как ?
}
```

Спасибо

Comment: [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/EVuQixXzcA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве параметра можно использовать структуру. Что-то вроде этого:

```
type myParam struct {
    a int
    b string
    c float64
}

func myFunc(args myParam) float64 {
    return args.c
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myFunc(myParam{a: 1, c: 5}))
}
```

Comment: ну это не совсем то. Это тоже самое что передать объект класса в питоне, можно но чет никто не юзает)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что Вам требуется, то могу предложить сделать функцию-обертку:

```
func barwrapper(args map) {
    bar(args["a"], args["b"], args["c"])
}
```

Только вот не помню, нужен ли тут указатель...

Comment: Указатель не нужен, `map` и `slice` референсные типы и так.

Answer (score -1):

Насколько мне известно, то никак. Почитайте книжку какую-нибудь чтоли.